# EditText Limit Upto 5 contacts only

Tags: android, sqlite, contacts

I am making a **Panic App**, and allowing user to **add multiple contacts** and showing selected contacts into EditText by doing Tap on **Add to Contacts** button, whenever he/she wants to add.

In EditText getting something like this: 9867XXXXXX, 9866XXXXXX, ......

**Changes i require:**

**Limit** upto **5 Contacts** only

I know how to limit for characters length in EditText, but don't know how to limit of 5 contacts only ?

```
     private Button btnAddContacts ;
     private EditText editContacts

    ..............................
    btnAddContacts = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAddContacts);
    btnAddContacts.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                 Intent it= new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                 it.setType(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
                 startActivityForResult(it, 1);
            }
        });

        @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            if (data != null) {
             Uri uri = data.getData();

            if (uri != null) {
             Cursor c = null;
             try {
             c = getContentResolver().query(uri, new String[]{ 
             ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,  
             ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE },
             null, null, null);

             if (c != null && c.moveToFirst()) {
              String number = c.getString(0);
              int type = c.getInt(1);
              showSelectedNumber(type, number);
               }
              } finally {
             if (c != null) {
               c.close();
             }
          }
        }
      }
    }

        public void showSelectedNumber(int type, String number) {

            if(editContacts != null && editContacts.getText().toString().length()==0)
                editContacts.setText(number);
           else
                if(editContacts != null) editContacts.append(","+number);

        }
```

Comment: You can use a flag `onActivityResult` if it reaches to 5 then discard any more change/saving. Show proper message.

Comment: @VikalpPatel i know how to limit for characters length in EditText but don't know how to limit for contacts

Comment: In `changes i require` it seems like you have asked multiple questions by posting only one question.  That also makes it `Too Broad`. Please consider asking another question, specially in case of **database**.

Comment: You need to use Stringtokenizer on your edittext gettext and count nooftokens if tokens are 5 then dont call contactlist...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a flag say `maxNoContacts`

Snippet:

```
public YourActivity extends Activity
{
int maxNoContacts = 0; 

 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
 {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    ...
    btnAddContacts.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     if(maxNoContacts <5 ) 
       {
         Intent it= new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
         it.setType(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
         startActivityForResult(it, 1);
       }
    else
      {
              //show toast saying you added maximum no of contacts.
      }

    }
    });
 }
```

//Update maxNoContacts if contacts fetched properly.

```
  @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (data != null) {
     Uri uri = data.getData();

    if (uri != null) {
     Cursor c = null;
     try {

     c = getContentResolver().query(uri, new String[]{ 
     ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,  
     ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE },
     null, null, null);

     if (c != null && c.moveToFirst()) {
      String number = c.getString(0);
      int type = c.getInt(1);

       maxNoContacts++; //Increment maxNoContacts if it fetches contact properly.          

      showSelectedNumber(type, number);
       }
      } finally {
     if (c != null) {
       c.close();
     }
    }
  }
 }
}



}
```

Comment: thanks bro ... :) and may i know how to control for the selection of duplicate numbers ?

Comment: @SunnyLoveU : Duplication handling can be achieved by so many ways. I suggest you to use store selected no. in array and on fetching check with stored array. :)